# Can I install Windows 7 Ultimate (x64) on top of Windows 7 Home Premium (x64)?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

Will I retain all my programs/documents/settings?

This is not Anytime Upgrade route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can, and even if I did, I wouldn't have taken a chance. If it does not appear as an upgrade, then you're basically installing a new OS, leading to potential loss of data.Backup everything before trying this.

Comment: You could try it as a 'repair' install, but i wouldn't like to say if it would install correctly - it certainly wouldn't retain your settings, Documents would be unaffected and programs would probably be ok... Depending on what dll's they used...

Comment: I wouldn't take a chance either way - if the installer does not recognize an 'upgradeable' version installed, it slips back into 'install mode'. Next thing you know, the machine reboots and you're faced with a dialog asking you which disk partition would you like to format and install on. ALWAYS BACK UP before trying something like that. You know what, always back up period.